# Flutter Integration Testing- How to go back to previous screen when no back button available on screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

How to go back to previous screen when no back button available on screen? 
Additional Information: I am trying to automate integration testing for flutter app. There is no back button on screen which I can use to go back screen. 
Additional information: I am writing integration tests, for same I need to go back to previous screen. And due to design there is no back button on screen, I need to do by scripts only.

Comment: You won't answer, for developing prospective or testing?

Comment: Testing perspective

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me for OpenContainers from the animations package:

```
  final NavigatorState navigator = tester.state(find.byType(Navigator));
  navigator.pop();
  await tester.pump();
```

It's used in the flutter package's tests:

https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/63040337424f345452a5e07632774e6585329ac0/packages/animations/test/open_container_test.dart#L234

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of the test is to stress and verify the `WillPopScope` callbacks as well, the following approach can be used:

```
final dynamic widgetsAppState = _._tester.state(find.byType(WidgetsApp));
await widgetsAppState.didPopRoute();
```

This is used in the Flutter official repository for testing: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/will_pop_test.dart

Note that this approach also works to simulate a ***back button pressed*** on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's maybe a little bit late, however there are two possible ways to achieve this:

```
final backButton = find.byTooltip('Back');

await driver.tap(backButton);
```

or:

```
await driver.tap(find.pageBack());
```

Answer (score 1):

My emulador defaulf locale is "en_US" so I use the word "Back" as tooltip and it is working.

```
final backButton = find.byTooltip("Back");
await tester.tap(backButton);
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this as ios provided

```
theme: ThemeData(
pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
  builders: {
    TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
    TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
  }
 )
),
```