# How to test system back button tap in Flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I want to test system back button press in my flutter integration test.

Child screen is presented as model view and there is a close button 'X' to dismiss the screen.
I can already detect the 'X' button tap and test the go back scenario.
2nd test scenario, I want to simulate the system back button tap. I have tried below script, but seems not working

```
await Process.run(
  'adb', 
  <String>['shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_BACK'], 
  runInShell: true,
);
```

I also tried some other ways mentioned here [Flutter Integration Testing- How to go back to previous screen when no back button available on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044829/flutter-integration-testing-how-to-go-back-to-previous-screen-when-no-back-butt)

Nothing is working for me. If anyone has done this, please share the solution.
My flutter version `Flutter 2.10.3`

Answer (score 0):

Can you add to this button key? And then smth like this:

```
await driver.waitFor(find.byKey(Keys.backButton), timeout: Duration(seconds: 5));
```